# Why does the coop baby for multiplayer magnetize to the bottom right corner?

Tags: wii-u, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

When I use the coop baby for multiplayer why does it magnetize to the bottom right corner, when I try to move only the d-pad works and I can't go right, is this intentional? If not how do I fix it.

Comment: It sounds like when you powered up the controller the movement stick was engaged in the top left corner. This will cause the system to believe that that corner is the "neutral" position for the stick. Is this something that is happening over multiple attempts to play the game?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you powered up the controller you're using for P2 with the control stick towards the direction the baby is magnetizing towards. To fix, reconnect the controller by going to home-controller settings-change player order. Simply reconnect with the analog stick untouched, and presto!